# Intellij with ember error: "you have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use build command"

Tags: ember.js, intellij-idea

I have created a project which is configured to use ember-cli on the webapp folder before launching the resulting code, however I get that error when the ember compiler is called.

Here are some pictures:
[picture1]
[picture2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LZvf.jpg)

Here is the project folder. I have done ember init on the webapp folder:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEW1.jpg)

Is it something related to ember or is it something related to my run configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is duplicated. As I mention in another your post, you should run `ember init` in that folder. You don't have ember project structure yet

Comment: I have run ember init on the original project, but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Not original project root. Where is your ember root directory?

Comment: Ok, change working directory in config to point to webapp directory